# Summarise/reshape data in R

Tags: r

For an example dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:18, region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b"), class = "factor"), age.cat = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("0-18", 
"19-35", "36-50", "50+"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", 
"region", "age.cat"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

I want to reshape the data, as detailed below:

```
region 0-18 19-35 36-50 50+
a      2    3     2     1
b      4    2     1     3
```

Do I simply aggregate or reshape the data?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `reshape2`:

```
install.packages('reshape2')
library(reshape2)

df1 <- melt(df, measure.vars = 'age.cat')
df1 <- dcast(df1, region ~ value)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do it just using `table`:

```
 table(df$region, df$age.cat)

    0-18 19-35 36-50 50+
  a    2     3     2   1
  b    4     2     1   3
```

Comment: Only (minor) issue here is the column name for 'region' gets lost.